# Why does the <a> tag sit BELOW an <img> on screen (Firefox 4 + Chrome only!)

Tags: html, css, xhtml, hyperlink, image

I'm not sure if this is a glitch/quirk in the latest Firefox and Chrome, but I've got a `<img>` tag that's been encapsulated by an `<a>` tag to turn the image into a link.

The problem arises in that the click box for the link sits below the image. The image is also clickable, but the dead space under the image is clickable as well.

The `<img>` has a left and bottom margin rule applied to it, which I think is what's causing the issue, but I don't understand why... I've also tried using explicit `</img>` closing tags as that didn't solve the issue either.

Internet Explore 8 works as expected! Does not display the issue below. It shows the  box below the image, but the dead space is not clickable in IE 8. Which is how I think it should work.

Here's an image to clarify what I mean: [image]

I've just added a rule to border all `<a>` tags.

And here's the code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 1px solid #F00;
    }

    #testimg        {
        margin-left: 20%;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div><a href="#"><img id="testimg" alt="" src="imgs/landing/popup_sendbtn.png" /></a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is driving me crazy! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A live example on http://jsfiddle.net would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clickable area beneath your `<img>` is where textual content would supposedly go in an `<a>` element.

If you want only the image area to be clickable, give your `<a>` the same width and height, make it `display: block`, and move your margins to the `<a>`.

```
a {
    display: block;
    width: /* width of your image */;
    height: /* height of your image */;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

Comment: It's a problem of margins, not the inline elements. a expands to the size of the image it wraps, even if it's inline.

Comment: @Headshota: Yeah I got confused at first but I fixed my answer as quickly as I could. Oops.

Comment: Thanks! Moving the margins to the `<a>` tag and adding `display: block` did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You have a margin in the img. Move them to the a tag and it might fix it.